# Can't execute window.open from Chrome Snippet

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am using Chrome source snippets but I can't execute a window.open comman.

`myWindow = window.open(window.location.href, "", "width=1320, height=770");`

I just get "undefined" in the console. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the pop-up blocker is stopping you from opening a new window. After a pop-up is blocked there's an option in the URL field that let's you enable popups for the current domain.

[image]